# Extraer registros únicos con valores diferentes en una columna

Tags: sql, oracle

Me he topado con un problema en BD, tengo el siguiente escenario: Necesito obtener todos los registros que tengan solamente id 15 y id 16, no otros, por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente tabla

```
folio     | id |indicador
1907050173| 1  |1
1907050173| 6  |1
1907050173| 16 |1
1907050173| 15 |1
1907050174| 16 |1
1907050174| 15 |1
```

El resultado de la consulta debe ser el folio **1907050174** únicamente ya que es el único que cumple con la regla, he intentado con varias condicionales oracle (in, case, exist)pero siempre me trae los registros que no necesito.

Gracias desde ya

Comment: ¿si colocas `WHERE id IN (15,16)` no te funciona?. Saludos.

Comment: En este ejemplo, me traeria ambos registros por que ambos tienen 15 y 16, pero solo necesito el segundo. Y si el IN ya lo había probado

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que necesitas todos aquellos números de folio que cumplan con ambos criterios,es decir, `id` 15 y 16 o solamente el registro con el `id` 15, que también tenga un `id` 16?

Comment: Con ambos, ya que es una tabla en la cual se puede repetir el numero folio teniendo un id de catalogo diferente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, puedes hacer un *join* entre la misma tabla para obtener todos los registros que tienen `ID` tanto 15 como 16.

Luego, sobre este resultado, excluir a todos los que tengan algún otro ID, haciendo una sub-consulta `not exists`.

En código, se vería algo como:

```
select a.folio
  from MiTabla a
       inner join MiTabla b on b.folio = a.folio and b.id = 16
 where a.id = 15
   and not exists (select 1
                     from MiTabla c
                    where c.folio = a.folio
                      and c.id not in (15, 16))
```

Comment: excelente, funciono perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

Con una primer consulta, puedes agrupar por `folio`  y filtrar mediante el `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id)` aquellos que únicamente tengan los dos `id`, y luego un simple `JOIN` a esta consulta podría terminar de completar lo que buscas:

```
SELECT *
       FROM TuTabla T1
       INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT folio,
                        MAX(id) id
                        FROM TuTabla
                        WHERE id IN (15, 16)
                        GROUP BY folio
                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1
       ) T2
       ON T1.folio = T2.folio
       AND T1.id = T2.id
```

Comment: Me sigue repitiendo los registros, pero ya encontré solución con la respuesta del amigo @jachguate, gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0):

Este problema yo lo habría resuelto añadiendo (virtualmente) una columna que tome el valor 1 o 0 en función de que `id` valga 15 o 16, o no:

```
+------------+----+         +------------+----+------+
| folio      | id |         | folio      | id | flag |
+------------+----+         +------------+----+------+
| 1907050173 |  1 |         | 1907050173 |  1 |    0 |
| 1907050173 |  6 |         | 1907050173 |  6 |    0 |
| 1907050173 | 16 |    =>   | 1907050173 | 16 |    1 |
| 1907050173 | 15 |         | 1907050173 | 15 |    1 |
| 1907050174 | 16 |         | 1907050174 | 16 |    1 |
| 1907050174 | 15 |         | 1907050174 | 15 |    1 |
+------------+----+         +------------+----+------+
```

Luego, al agrupar por `folio`, nos quedamos con los que tengan sólo 1 en `flag`: el mínimo será 1 y la suma valdrá 2 (en este caso).

No puedo probarlo con Oracle, pero en MySQL lo he hecho así:

```
SELECT   folio,
         MIN(IF(id IN (15,16), 1, 0)) AS minflag,
         SUM(IF(id IN (15,16), 1, 0)) AS cnt
FROM     tabla
GROUP BY folio
HAVING   minflag=1 AND cnt=2

+------------+---------+-----+
| folio      | minflag | cnt |
+------------+---------+-----+
| 1907050174 |       1 |   2 |
+------------+---------+-----+
```

Si quitas el `HAVING` verás que para `folio=1907050173` `minflag` es igual a 0, por lo que lo descartamos; y si tuvieras un folio para el que `id` valiera solamente 15 o 16, `minflag` cumpliría pero `sum` sería igual a 1 y también lo descartaríamos.

En lo anterior doy por hecho que en la tabla la tupla *(folio, id)* no se puede repetir.

Answer (score 0):

Quizas a esta altura ya no necesites este codigo, pero quizas te sirva para una proxima oportunidad. Aqui te dejo mi version :

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=664c4af5d82e97a447cd91dcb1211ae8

```
create table Registro (
Folio number(12),
id number(3), 
indicador number(1));

insert into Registro values (1907050173,1,1);
insert into Registro values (1907050173,6,1);
insert into Registro values (1907050173,16,1);
insert into Registro values (1907050173,15,1);
insert into Registro values (1907050174,16,1);
insert into Registro values (1907050174,15,1);
insert into Registro values (1907050175,2,1);
insert into Registro values (1907050175,3,1);

select * from registro;

select a.folio
from registro a,
     (select folio, count(distinct id) qty
      from registro
      group by folio) b
where a.id in (15,16) 
and a.folio = b.folio
group by a.folio, b.qty
having count(distinct a.id) = 2 and count(distinct a.id) = b.qty;
```

Si te fijas, he agregado un tercer código que posee igual 2 registros pero ninguno corresponde a los id 15 o 16, lo utilice para probar que no se considerara otro código con 2 id.

Espero sea de ayuda.